Shell Script to Normalize the data
We have requirement to normalize the data ... Item field is comma delimited and irregular and it may have any items from 0 to max (lets say 100)
Input:
key1|desc field|item1,item2,item3,item4|extra field
key2|desc field|item1,item2,item3|extra field

Output:
key1|desc field|item1|extra field
key1|desc field|item2|extra field
key1|desc field|item3|extra field
key1|desc field|item4|extra field
key2|desc field|item1|extra field
key2|desc field|item2|extra field
key2|desc field|item3|extra field

is there a way we can achive it through Unix command or shell script? Please advise.

What did you try ?

This is probably a good job for "miller" (mlr, https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.13.0/ ) See for exemple : https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.13.0/record-heterogeneity/

Please [edit] your question and add your operating system. Also, can you have a | inside one of the items? Can you have something like key2|desc field|"item1|item2",item3|extra field?

@terdon My fault I removed the "linux" tag.

@Archemar removing the tag is fine, just remember to add it to the question. Sanjay, are you using Linux or UNIX? They are two completely different things.

Is it always the third column that needs normalizing?

Using Miller (mlr) to "explode" the comma-delimited subfields of the 3rd field in the pipe-delimited input:
$ mlr --nidx --fs pipe nest --evar , -f 3 file
key1|desc field|item1|extra field
key1|desc field|item2|extra field
key1|desc field|item3|extra field
key1|desc field|item4|extra field
key2|desc field|item1|extra field
key2|desc field|item2|extra field
key2|desc field|item3|extra field


I dont see this command available in my Unix shell .. tried man and help .. is that a utility that need to be installed for the purpose? Please advise.

@SanjayDubey we can only advise if you tell us what operating system you are using.

@SanjayDubey Like all other utilities, Miller has to be installed for you to be able to use it.

Nice, I didn't know of that verb

using awk:
awk -F'|' '
{
  split($3, items, ","); 
  for (i=1; i in items; i++) 
    print $1 "|" $2 "|" items[i] "|" $4
}'

This will split the 3rd column into an array named items delimited by ,.  For each item in items it will print a new line using the value of each other column from the original line.

you could just set OFS to "|" so you wouldn't have to write them explicitly in the print statement.

Here's a Perl approach which assumes that you never have | inside any of the items:
$ perl -F'\|' -ane '@items = split(/,/,$F[2]); print join("|",@F[0,1],$_,@F[3..$#F]) for @items' file
key1|desc field|item1|extra field
key1|desc field|item2|extra field
key1|desc field|item3|extra field
key1|desc field|item4|extra field
key2|desc field|item1|extra field
key2|desc field|item2|extra field
key2|desc field|item3|extra field

The -n flag tells perl to read its input line by line and apply the script given by -e to each line. The -a flag tells perl to behave like awk and split its input on the character given by -F and save the result into the array @F.
Then, in the script, we split the third field (numbering starts at 0, so $F[2] is the third field) on commas and save the result into the array @items. Then, for each element of the @items array, we print the result of joining the first two fields with a | (which gives us back the beginning of the original input line), then the current item (the value of the special variable $_), and then the rest of the array. All joined with |.

Using any awk:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    n = split($3, f, ",")
    for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
        $3 = f[i]
        print
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
key1|desc field|item1|extra field
key1|desc field|item2|extra field
key1|desc field|item3|extra field
key1|desc field|item4|extra field
key2|desc field|item1|extra field
key2|desc field|item2|extra field
key2|desc field|item3|extra field

Passing the field position 3 as an argument to a shell script calling awk as the OP requested in a comment:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pos=$1
shift

awk -v pos="$pos" '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
    {
        n = split($pos, f, ",")
        for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
            $pos = f[i]
            print
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"


$ ./tst.sh 3 file
key1|desc field|item1|extra field
key1|desc field|item2|extra field
key1|desc field|item3|extra field
key1|desc field|item4|extra field
key2|desc field|item1|extra field
key2|desc field|item2|extra field
key2|desc field|item3|extra field


How can we invoke through .sh using parameterization for field position $3 ... Thank you

@SanjayDubey I added an example of usage like that.

Upvoted. You corrected me a thousand times. But didn't tell me about for (i=1; i in ar; i++). I'm hurt today. Still thanks.

Thank you Ed, is there a way we can pass multiple parameters for File Delimiter, field delimiter, etc... Also, if you could guide om awk function and variables.

@PrabhjotSingh sorry I missed you previously with that one. Fair warning - there may be other dark corners I haven't warned you about yet :-).

@SanjayDubey yes but you're asking me to teach you the basics of both shell programming and awk, I'm sorry but I won't be able to do that in comments under a SE answer because that's not the purpose of this site and Chameleon Questions are strongly discouraged. Accept an answer to the question you asked here, then try to figure out whatever else you want to do next for yourself and then post a new followup question if you run into trouble.

So I was able to integrate the code in my she'll script but requirement is to parameterize the file separator (|) and field separator (,) . Also need to force make changes in the input file, instead redirect.. please advise.. multiple variable declaration seems bot working..

My advice is the same as before -  accept an answer to the question you asked here then ask a new question about your new requirements if you can't figure out how to implement them yourself. Again, Chameleon Questions are strongly discouraged.

here is the script below .. echo "Script name: $0"
echo "Number of Arguments Passed to the Script :$#"
filedir="$1"
file="$2"
filedelimiter="$3"
normfieldpos="$4"
normfielddelimiter="$5"

##COMMAND TO NORMALIZE THE FILE CONTENT USING FIELD POSITION AND FIELD DELIMITER
awk -v normfieldpos=$normfieldpos -v normfielddelimiter=$normfielddelimiter -v filedelimiter=$filedelimiter 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{ n = split($normfieldpos, f, ",")
for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) {
$normfieldpos = f[i]
print
}
}' $filedir/$file >$filedir/$file"_normalized"

We are looking at parameterize FIELD and Column delimiter.. Please let me know if I should post a separate question for that..

Don't add information in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed.

Same advice as I already gave you previously above and under your SO question - accept an answer to the question you asked here then ask a new question about your new requirements showing your attempted code and sample input/output if you can't figure out how to implement them yourself. See [ask] and look at other questions that have been upvoted an answered for examples.

@EdMorton Thank you for the encouragement ... This is now fixed and good to close.. Though took me several iterations.. :)

You're welcome. Questions don't get closed when answered, the person who posted the question upvotes and/or accept answers and the question stays open for others to benefit from in future. Again, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

here's a very short python3 solution; put it in a file (say normalize.py), make it executable (chmod 755 normalize.py) and run it on your input (./normalize.py < your_input_data.file)
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
  key, desc, items, extra = line.split("|")
  for item in items.split(","):
    if item:
      print(f"{key}|{desc}|{item}|{extra.strip()}")

Assumptions: no | anywhere except as separators of columns, exactly 4 columns per input line, and within the items list, no commas except for these that separate the items.

Note that your question basically screams that you would probably want a better relational data model than this; in a classical relational database design, you'd make two tables out of this:

table "itemtypes" with columns 'key' (a unique, primary key), 'description' and 'extra'
table "items" with column 'item' and column 'type_key', which references 'itemtypes.key'.


That seems to add an empty line after each line. It also fails with an error if a line doesn't have exactly 4 |-separated fields or cannot be decoded into text in the locale's charmap. It also skips empty ,-separated elements.

the skipping of empty elements seemed intended; but that's interpretation. Limitations as listed – and sensible. You're right, I keep the \n from extra, let's fix that.

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)
~$ raku -ne 'my @a = .split("|").map: *.split(",");  my @b;
             given @a.pairs { for .values {
                 when .key == 0  { @b = $_.value }  #(A);
                 when .value.elems > 1  { @b = [X] @b, .value }  #(B);
                 default { @b .= map( -> $b { $b, .value }) }
             }}; put $_ for @b;  say ""; @b = ();'  file.txt

Above is an answer written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku features case statements, shown here in the given/when format. These statements are used to create a recipient @b array, which is then output.
In the first statement the input line is split on the pipe-character, then each resulting element is mapped into and further split on commas. Saved into the @a array, this object is used in pair format, which provides .key (indexing) and .value functionality.
Each element is iterated through using a for loop, testing via the following when statements:

#(A):  Automatically add the first row to the recipient @b array. FYI, this means the simple code above won't expand multiple elements within the first column (so think of the first column as containing indivisible keys). Add a line-number to your datafile as column 1 to circumvent this limitation,
#(B):  When a column contains more than one element, take the @b array and [X] (meta) cross-product expand[1]. Replace @b with this expansion.
default: String-concatenate each cell's value onto the end of every element of the @b array.

Sample Input (OP's file with no-spaces and extra test line):
key1|desc_field|item1,item2,item3,item4|extra_field
key2|desc_field|item1,item2,item3|extra_field
key3|desc_field|item1,item2|itemA,itemB|extra_field

Sample Output (joining columns on spaces and adding blank lines between input rows):
key1 desc_field item1 extra_field
key1 desc_field item2 extra_field
key1 desc_field item3 extra_field
key1 desc_field item4 extra_field

key2 desc_field item1 extra_field
key2 desc_field item2 extra_field
key2 desc_field item3 extra_field

key3 desc_field item1 itemA extra_field
key3 desc_field item1 itemB extra_field
key3 desc_field item2 itemA extra_field
key3 desc_field item2 itemB extra_field

To join columns on something else (e.g. | space-pipe-space), a fun and powerful way is to declare a new J infix operator, using it alone or in conjunction with the X cross-product operator:
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN sub infix:<J> ($x, $y) { ($x,$y).join(" | ") }; 
             my @a = .split("|").map: *.split(",");  my @b;
             given @a.pairs { for .values {
                 when .key == 0 { @b = $_.value }  #(A);
                 when .value.elems > 1 { @b = @b  XJ  .value.cache }  #(B);
                 default { @b .= map( -> $b { $b   J  .value.cache }) }
             }}; put $_ for @b;  say ""; @b = ();'  file.txt
key1 | desc_field | item1 | extra_field
key1 | desc_field | item2 | extra_field
key1 | desc_field | item3 | extra_field
key1 | desc_field | item4 | extra_field

key2 | desc_field | item1 | extra_field
key2 | desc_field | item2 | extra_field
key2 | desc_field | item3 | extra_field

key3 | desc_field | item1 | itemA | extra_field
key3 | desc_field | item1 | itemB | extra_field
key3 | desc_field | item2 | itemA | extra_field
key3 | desc_field | item2 | itemB | extra_field


[1] Example: raku -e 'say <A B C> X 1..3' returns ((A 1) (A 2) (A 3) (B 1) (B 2) (B 3) (C 1) (C 2) (C 3)). 
https://docs.raku.org/language/control#index-entry-case_statements_(given)
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-X
https://docs.raku.org/language/functions#Defining_operators
https://raku.org

Using sed, assuming the exact input with no surprises:
$ sed -E 's/\|([^|]*,[^|]*)\|/|"\{\1\}"|/;s/^|$/"/g;s/(.*)/printf "%s\n" \1/e' input.txt
key1|desc field|item1|extra field
key1|desc field|item2|extra field
key1|desc field|item3|extra field
key1|desc field|item4|extra field
key2|desc field|item1|extra field
key2|desc field|item2|extra field
key2|desc field|item3|extra field

This is a silly answer and will fail spectacularly if the comma-separated items contain spaces, or if there are any quoted commas, or if you try to separate more than one field with commas. (And probably many other special cases I haven't thought of.)
Explanation:

s/\|([^|]*,[^|]*)\|/|"\{\1\}"|/g: Replace any field x,y,z that contains a comma with "{x,y,z}".
s/^|$/"/g: Put " at the beginning and end of each line. Now the rest of the line is quoted.
s/(.*)/printf "%s\n" \1/e: Open another bash (or zsh, or sh) shell and call printf "%s\n" on the resulting line. The shell performs brace expansion on each line to turn it into multiple strings, one with each option. Then printf prints each string on its own line.

